# Windows application server communication issue

Tags: windows-phone

I recently developed a windows phone application using phonegap(HTML5, CSS) in visual studio and generated the deployable XAP file. When I registered my device with my developer account I was able to install my application locally and was able to do server communication as well. But when I submit the same XAP file to store and then download from store, the server communication is failing. As this issue is observed only at store I am not able to debug the issue.

My question is how can the same application show different behaviours when deployed locally & downloaded from store.

Note: I am doing ajax requests for server communication.
Please let me know if some permissions need to be given while submitting to store or any work around needed from me to fix this issue. Requesting a response soon.